# What is wrong with this grammar?

Tags: meaning

In conversation with 2 native-German speakers, I said:

> Woher können wir wissen, dass ein Kniegelenk zum Beispiel nicht kaputtgehen und verursachen würde, **ihn hinzufallen**?

They corrected me with:

> Woher können wir wissen, dass ein Kniegelenk zum Beispiel nicht kaputtgehen und verusachen würde, **dass er hinfällt**?

Do you agree that "ihn hinzufallen" is wrong? If so, why?

Here is the English that I wish to translate:

> How do we know when a knee joint, for instance, won’t be thrown out of kilter and keel him over.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Hinfallen* is an intransitive verb therefore you can't apply it to someone else (as indicated by an accusative object grammatically).

A valid construction would be:

> ... dass ein Kniegelenk kaputtgehen und ihn hinfallen lassen könnte.

This works, since *lassen* accepts an accusative object (and the infinitive verb to indicate, what process one admits).

*Zu Boden werfen* would be another phrase allowing an object.

Comment: I would add that _verursachen_ + _zu_ + infinitive does not really work as the thing that is causing an action is generally not the subject of the action that is caused. _zu_ + infinitive can only be used when the implicit subject of the infinitive is identical to the subject or an object of the introducing sentence.

Answer (score 3):

*Verursachen ... ihn hinzufallen* is wrong because combining an infinitive with an accusative in this way works only with certain verbs.

It works with *lassen*, as in the version given in guidot's answer.

It also works with verbs of perception, for example *sehen* or *hören*:

> Er sah ihn hinfallen. (He saw him fall.)

Notice that there is no *zu*, so it's *hinfallen*, not *hinzufallen*.

It does not work with most other verbs, including *verursachen*.